# Can I Travel USA

Tags: visas

I am from India, I have visa for USA it expires on September 8th I am planning to Travel September 4th and return on October 1st. Does it possible? Can I travel to the USA from India just 4 days before my visa expires? I never traveled to the USA before, but I was issued a visa valid for 2 months. I mentioned to the visa office my dates of travel, yet the visa I was granted is expiring before my expected arrival date. Is it possible for me to stay in the USA for one month after the expiration of my visa? and does it effect my future visa applications to the USA?

Comment: my visa is B1-B2

Comment: Wait, you say "the visa I was granted is expiring before my expected arrival date".  But you also say "it expires on September 8th".

Comment: yes it expires after I enter into the usa I enter on 4th and it will expire on 8th does it possible to stay there for one month

Answer (score 0):

You can travel with a visa that's close to expiration, but you will have to leave again before on on the expiration date. And as your return ticket is for after the expiration date, it's highly likely you won't be allowed into the country, if the airline even lets you board the flight (as they're held fined by the US for passengers who are denied entry).
So no, you'll need to get a new visa.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can travel to USA if your visa is going to expire.Because USA has a very strict rules about the visas and passport.